# If else statment not work in my app

Tags: objective-c

I´m making a dictionary (this is my test app)
here is my code which not work:

```
- (IBAction) btnClickMe_Clicked:(id)sender {


    NSString *kw = s.text;

    NSString *encodedkw =  [kw stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *mms = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", encodedkw];

    if (mms=NULL){
        iMessageLabel.text=@"put text";
    } else if (mms=@"a"){
        iMessageLabel.text=@"this is a";
    } else if (mms=@"b"){
    iMessageLabel.text=@"this is b";
    }


}
```

anybody have some idea with this ?
thanks
ALex

Comment: What isn't working?  Does your code throw an exception? Crash and burn? Not produce the desired results?

Comment: What language is it? Can you provide a testcase demonstrating the behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `==` on NSString objects. Try doing this:

```
if (encodedkw == nil){
    iMessageLabel.text=@"put text";
} else if ([encodedkw isEqualToString:@"a"]){
   iMessageLabel.text=@"this is a";
} else if ([encodedkw isEqualToString:@"b"]){
   iMessageLabel.text=@"this is b";
}
```

`mms` should be equal to `encodedkw` so I switched to using that. Also I'm using `isEqualToString` for string comparison. Finally, I've changed the null check to check against `nil` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: For correctness sake, shouldn't it be:

if (mms==NIL)...

because Apple's APIs return "NIL" instead of "NULL"?  (That being said, isn't [stringWithFormat ...] a static function that always returns something?)

Comment: Agreed on nil and the fact that it should never be nil. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

May it happen, that you need to call some kind of string manipulation routine like [compare](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:) to compare strings, not just comparing the pointers?

Besides `mms=NIL` means assignment `NIL` to `mms` not comparison desired.

**Upd.:** `NIL` does not mean empty string. You should write `[mms length] == 0` instead to see if the string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You've used = rather than ==